# How prevent script from reloading when using hapi.js reply().hold()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, hapi.js

I've just started using hapi.js and have run into a problem when trying to defer the response for a route.

I successfully defer the response for the `/query` route using this code:

```
server.route([{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/query',
    config: {
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            var response = reply().hold();              
            db = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].db;
            someFxn(callbackFxn, request, response);    
        }
    }

}]);

var someFxn(cb, req, res){
   var raw = {}; 
   //... do lots of stuff that can take a long time
   cb(req, res, raw); 
}

var callbackFxn = function(request, response, data){
    response.source = data; 
    response.send(); 
}
```

The problem I am having is that sometimes `someFxn()` takes a long time to execute and this seems to perhaps cause a timeout and the request is made again.  How can I change the timeout value for the request so that it does not fire the request again?

I really appreciate any advice/leads anyone can give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be hitting the default Node.js socket timeout of 2 minutes. You can override it using the route config option `config.timeout.socket`:

[From docs:](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options)

> `timeout` - define timeouts for processing durations:
>
> ...
>
> `socket` - by default, node
>   sockets automatically timeout after 2 minutes. Use this option to
>   override this behavior. Defaults to `undefined` which leaves the node
>   default unchanged. Set to `false` to disable socket timeouts.

Set it like this to disable timeouts entirely for the route:

```
server.route([{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/query',
    config: {
        timeout: {
            socket: false
        },
        handler: function(request, reply) {

            ...
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! That did it! I will be accepting your answer.